# Maven plugin execution error

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am getting below error while executing goal

```
jaxws:wsimport
```

below is plugin snippet from my pom.xml

```
<plugin> 
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId> 
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
            <version>2.1</version> 
            <executions>
                <execution> 
                    <id>wsdla</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    **<!-- if you have one more than one execution node put your configuration here-->** 
                    <goals> 
                        <goal>wsimport</goal> 
                    </goals>            
                </execution> 
            </executions>
            <configuration> 
                <packageName>com.mycee.project.model</packageName> 
                <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                <wsdlFiles>
                      <wsdlFile>
                          ${basedir}/src/wsdl/a.wsdl
                      </wsdlFile>            
                </wsdlFiles>
                      <bindingDirectory>
                          ${basedir}/src/wsdl/binding
                      </bindingDirectory>
                      <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

below is error i am seeing  i am not sure why i am getting this error , tried to search for error and solution provided are already implemented , it is not part of plugin management . i am trying to generate source file from wsdl file . my project is build into eclipse and following maven directory struture.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default-cli) on project AECore: Execution default-cli of goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport failed: String index out of range: -1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport (default-cli) on project AECore: Execution default-cli of goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport failed: String index out of range: -1
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:225)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons:jaxws-maven-plugin:2.3:wsimport failed: String index out of range: -1
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
```

Comment: what is your jdk version? have you included `com.sun.xml.ws` dependency?

Comment: yes dependency is there ,,,also JDK version into POM is 1.6

Comment: Please read the following POM snippet carefully, cause it has additional tags according to JDK 1.6 : [usage](https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/jaxws-maven-plugin/usage.html)

Comment: **i have resolved this issue by pointing jdk instead of jre in eclipse**